# Magento 2 "out of stock label" on product page

Tags: magento2

I need to add “out of stock” string next to product option when product are out of stock on this list. Can someone help me? Link to img ->[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiF5u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Magento having that as default functionality.

You can see the code in the below path.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

Below is the default Magento code

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()):?>
    <div class="stock available">
        <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span>
    </div>
<?php else:?>
    <div class="stock unavailable">
        <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you have overridden this file in your theme and didn't have this code then you can add this code in your overridden file.

Like :- `app/design/frontend/THEME/NAME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Please check and let me know if any query for the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has default functionality to show out of stock at frontend with label.
we have admin configuration for it.
store =>  configuration => catalog